# How to show $2^{k+2}$ divides $3^{2^k}-1$ but $2^{k+3}$ doesn't?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I've got a task: Find highest power of 2 that divides $3^{2^k}-1$ 
so i wrote few terms and *guessed* that it's $2^{k+2}$, now i should show it. 
I tried by induction, but what i got appeals to me as a total nonsense, but i'm new to modular arithmetic, so i might be wrong!

I tried by induction, but i really failed here and turned out i showed that $$3^{2^{2k+1}} \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^{k+2})$$, so that isn't helpful.

I tried to work with eulers theorem and i got 
$$3^{\varphi(2^{k+2})} \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^{k+2}) \Leftrightarrow 3^{2^{k+1}} \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^{k+2})$$ but i wanted to show $$3^{2^k} \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^{k+2})$$

I'd really love to get some hints! Cheers

Comment: $3^{2^k}-1=(3^{2^{k-1}}+1)(3^{2^{k-1}}-1)$. You can continue this to get $k+1$ factors, each of which is even. The last factor is $(3+1)$, so at least $2^{k+2}$ divides $3^{2^k}$. Now you need to show that all the other factors (with plus signs) are not divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This is not much more than a reformulation of Nishant's comment).*
Let $v_2(n)$ denote the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, so $2^{v(n)}\mid n$ and $2^{v(n)+1}\not\mid n$.
Then

- If $m$ is even, we have $v_2(3^m-1)=v_2((3^{m/2}-1)(3^{m/2}+1))=v_2(3^{m/2}-1)+v_2(3^{m/2}+1)$
- If $m$ is even, we have
  $v_2(3^m+1)=1$ because $3^m\equiv 1\pmod 4$
- If $m$ is odd, then  $v(3^m-1)=1$ because $3^m\equiv -1\pmod 4$
- $v(3^1+1)=2$ (we do not need an explicit result for the general case $v(3^m+1)$ with $m$ odd

With this, you can show your conjecture $$v(3^{2^k}-1)=k+2$$ by induction for $k\ge1$. (Warning: For $k=0$, we have $v(3^{2^k}-1)=k+1$).